# Method does not Override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou criando um conversor e está me dando esse erro:

> **Method does not Override or implement a method from a supertype**

Código do conversor:

```
package com.mycompany.conversor;

import com.mycompany.entidades.agendaTipo;
import com.mycompany.repositorio.agendaTipoRepositorio;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.Converter;


@FacesConverter(forClass = agendaTipo.class)
public class agendaTipoConverter implements Converter{

    @Inject
    private agendaTipoRepositorio agendaTipoRepositorio;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context,
    UIComponent component, String value) {
        agendaTipo retorno = null;
        if (value != null && !"".equals(value)) {
            retorno = this.agendaTipoRepositorio.porId(new Long(value));
        }
        return retorno;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context,
    UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value != null) {
            agendaTipo agendaTipo = ((agendaTipo) value);
            return agendaTipo.getId() == null ? null : agendaTipo.getId().toString();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Poste o stacktrace completo e outra, suas classes começam com letra minúscula? Isso é fora do padrão mas é outra história.

Comment: Douglas o erro esta dando no netbeans ainda, pois é eu quando comecei com Java era assim primeira letra minuscula segunda maiuscula mas enfim. O erro dá dentro do netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Você está importando a classe "Converter" errada. A importação que você utilizou foi esta:

```
javax.persistence.Converter
```

Altere a importação para esta:

```
javax.faces.convert.Converter
```

O Converter que você utilizou faz parte da implementação do JPA, que não tem haver com os converters do JSF, e por serem classes diferentes os métodos para implementá-las obviamente também são diferentes.